# Change cart qty from onestep checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, onestepcheckout, knockout

I need to change cart qty via js while on the `/checkout` page(not in /checkout/cart). Then start the checkout process again with new data.

Is this possible?

Comment: using Magento default checkout or using any extension

Comment: /checkout i mean while you are on billing page